# Initializing custom delegates in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This seems to me like a trivial problem, but I was unable to find an answer, so here it is !

I'm writing a simple Delegated property which I want to use like this ( with an initial value ) :

```kotlin
val name by MyDelegate ("Initial Name")
```

Here is my class for the delegated Property :

```kotlin
class MyDelegate (val init: String) {
    var initialized = false
    operator fun getValue(thisRef:Any, property: KProperty<*>): String 
   {
        if (!initialized) { 
            setValue(thisRef,property,init)
            initialized = true
        }
        // return the actual value
    }
    operator fun setValue(thisRef:Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        // set value
    }
}
```

Is there a less ugly way to create a delegated property with an initialization, saving the use of one Boolean and one test every time ?

Thank very much you for your attention !

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. I guess your `MyDelegate` has some property that you didn't show in your example, because otherwise, how would you store/load the value? Then, you can just set this property to initial value.

Comment: Also, does this delegate do anything more? If not then how is it different than simple: `val name = "Initial Name"`?

Comment: Well the Delegate is about a LuaJ table, and explaining it here would complexify the thing and be out of point I think. Let's say for the sake of the example, that the value I'm setting with "set value" and getting with "get value" is stored on a web server, or in a database. The point of the delegate would be to use a simpler syntax

Comment: So if it reads the value from some remote place, then what is the purpose of this initial value? Assuming we just created `name` with "Initial Name" and now we read its contents - should it return "Initial Name" or fetch the real value and return it? And if it should return "Initial Name" then when it should read the real value?

Comment: A property's getter and setter should not perform thread-blocking actions like fetching from the network.

Comment: But still, above code seems to do nothing. If first call to `getValue()` always sets the value to initial then how is it different than doing the same in a constructor? The missing part in your code is what is returned in `else { }` branch, but I guess `init`. If your intended behavior is that if the first action on a newly created value is `get`, then we need to perform some kind of a background `set` operation, then I guess you did it right.

Comment: @broot
I edited the code, you were right, I was missing the second return in the get function. 
I'll try to explain myself better :
If I don't include the boolean "initialized", the only way to initialize the property is with `val name by MyDelegate() ; init { name = "Value" };` I want to do it with `val name by MyDelegate ("Value")` which is prettier, but I don't know how to do it properly

Comment: I don't mean the constructor of an object that owns `name`, but constructor of `MyDelegate` itself. I think doing something like: `MyDelegate { init { // set value to initial } }` is effectively the same as creating a delegate and immediately setting its value.

Comment: The problem is that I need the name of the property to set the value, which can only be supplied in the function get or set. If I could know its name in the constructor, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Ahh, ok, now I understand everything :-) You need to use [provideDelegate()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate). It lets you access `KProperty` during the delegate initialization.